# How to return to my app after facetime call ends in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios-4.2, facetime

How to return to my app after **Facetime** call ends in iPhone.

I referred this below answer but it's calling the facetime But not return to my App.

**NO just like when your app start a call there is no way to get your app back in the foreground after you close the call.
For your first question, you need to add the contact data (e-mail or phonenumber).
Also be aware that the facetime:// url scheme will work on any iPhone/iPod Touch even if they can't do facetime. If the device does not have facetime support it will just show a blank screen.**

share your ideas..

Comment: do you call facetime from your app?

Comment: yes. it's working fine but am not able to return to my app ,it's going out of the app.